# Why does Rails 2.0.2 Load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Why does this happen?

```
ruby script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.0.2)
>> exit
jay-z-mac-pro:justinz$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `RAILS_ROOT/config/environment.rb` file.  In it you can set and lock the Rails gem version to load.  Look for the line:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.0.2' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Change that to

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.3' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project is pinned to version 2.0.2. I haven't worked with Rails for quite some time, so I can't say for sure, but I believe this can be done in a config file.

Also, you should check if Rails is in your `vendor` directory (was that what it is called?). That's another way to force a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your config/environment.rb, it sets the Rails version for your application. It should be something like this:

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.5' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

script/console will load your application with the gems (including Rails) that you define in the config. rails is just the latest rails gem installed.

However, moving from Rails 2.0.2 to 2.3.3 is a pretty big change, you'll want to be careful about upgrading. Make sure to read the docs as it relates to your application.